# How can make for loops on this array code?

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop

My project include this code to get picture links in this array. I want to create images array with for loops.

```
 private void sliderPic(){
  List<String> sP=catalog_data_list.getCatalogImages();
  String[] urls;
      // Şimdilik bu yöntemle gelen resim sayısına göre dolduruyorum slider'ı.
   int spSize = sP.size();
  if (spSize==2)
      urls = new String[]{String.valueOf(sP.get(0)), String.valueOf(sP.get(1))};
  else if (spSize==1)
      urls = new String[]{String.valueOf(sP.get(0))};
  else if (spSize==3)
      urls = new String[]{String.valueOf(sP.get(0)), String.valueOf(sP.get(1)), String.valueOf(sP.get(2))};
  else if (spSize==4)
      urls = new String[]{String.valueOf(sP.get(0)), String.valueOf(sP.get(1)), String.valueOf(sP.get(2)),
              String.valueOf(sP.get(3))};
  else if (spSize==5)
      urls = new String[]{String.valueOf(sP.get(0)), String.valueOf(sP.get(1)), String.valueOf(sP.get(2)),
              String.valueOf(sP.get(3)), String.valueOf(sP.get(4))};
  else if (spSize==6)
      urls = new String[]{String.valueOf(sP.get(0)), String.valueOf(sP.get(1)), String.valueOf(sP.get(2)),
              String.valueOf(sP.get(3)), String.valueOf(sP.get(4)), String.valueOf(sP.get(5))};
  else if (spSize==7)
      urls = new String[]{String.valueOf(sP.get(0)), String.valueOf(sP.get(1)), String.valueOf(sP.get(2)),
              String.valueOf(sP.get(3)), String.valueOf(sP.get(4)), String.valueOf(sP.get(5)), String.valueOf(sP.get(6))};
  else if (spSize==8)
      urls = new String[]{String.valueOf(sP.get(0)), String.valueOf(sP.get(1)), String.valueOf(sP.get(2)),
              String.valueOf(sP.get(3)), String.valueOf(sP.get(4)), String.valueOf(sP.get(5)), String.valueOf(sP.get(6)),
              String.valueOf(sP.get(7))};
  else if (spSize==9)
      urls = new String[]{String.valueOf(sP.get(0)), String.valueOf(sP.get(1)), String.valueOf(sP.get(2)),
              String.valueOf(sP.get(3)), String.valueOf(sP.get(4)), String.valueOf(sP.get(5)), String.valueOf(sP.get(6)),
              String.valueOf(sP.get(7)), String.valueOf(sP.get(8))};
  else if (spSize==10)
      urls = new String[]{String.valueOf(sP.get(0)), String.valueOf(sP.get(1)), String.valueOf(sP.get(2)),
              String.valueOf(sP.get(3)), String.valueOf(sP.get(4)), String.valueOf(sP.get(5)), String.valueOf(sP.get(6)),
              String.valueOf(sP.get(7)), String.valueOf(sP.get(8)), String.valueOf(sP.get(9))};
```

I just tried this code to make for loop but it don't allow in syntax:
  if (spSize==2)

```
      urls = new String[]{for (int i=0;i>3;i++){String.valueOf(sP.get(0)), String.valueOf(sP.get(1))};}
```

Comment: `urls = new String[spSize]; for (int i = 0; i < spSize; i++) {urls[i] = String.valueOf(sP.get(i));}`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create an array of size `spSize`
- Loop on `sP`and populate the array

Something like:

```
urls = new String[spSize];
for (int i=0; i<spSize; i++) {
    urls[i] = sP.get(i) // already a String, no need to call String.valueOf except if sP can contains null values.
}
```

Your idea was good, but you can't use a loop as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Is `sP.get(i)` (you mean `sP`, not `Sp`, right?) really a String? Or could it be `null`? `String.valueOf(null)` is `"null"`, not `null`.